# Sculpting tools don't seem to work unless using remesh or dyntopo

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

I'm trying to learn sculpting but my brushes don't seem to work. The add and subtract just do their work in a general area no matter how smaller the radius of the brush is and the crease brush gives me a crease at highest power with several stroked along a already bulging crease. Help!

PS. I tried looking at other solutions but they were outdated or I wasn't able to find the options in blender.

My blend file : 
[image]

Thanks for the answer. It works amazing. I can't reply or upvote as of yet so hopefully you will be able to read this

Answer (score 1):

I was able to sculpt when I applied the two modifiers (mirror & sub) and filled the holes in Edit Mode (select all + f for fill). I don't know enough about the sculpt tools but maybe brushes like crease need closed meshes. Depending on what you want to do don't expect high resolution and details without Dyntopo on this one.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your answer before posting. I'll leave mine up as they complement each other, ok?

Comment: No sweat! :) Your idea is good as well, I think we wrote simultaneously. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're using modifiers: Mirror and Subdivision Surface.

Blenders modifiers get applied **after** the geometry is evaluated. This means your only sculpting on this very low poly mesh even though you can see the result of the modifiers.

[image: low poly]

Apply the modifiers first if you want to sculpt on their generated geometry.